# Tweak a URL and make the JQUERY trick work FULL CODE 100% FINISHED

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink

Well, this scenario may be familiar for some already because I ve been at it for quite a while but though closer than ever still has never worked. I am going to put it extremely clear and detailed to definitively nail it.

SCENARIO

We have one long URL line upon whose clicking 2 things should happen at once (the current situation is that it ony happens one of them 1 or 2)

1) A JQUERY is sensitive to the click AND opens a slide panel

2) This same JQUERY has another line which also makes a DIV inside that panel be populated (thanks to another PHP sql powered file)

So, the issue is with the line. Two have been proposed, none really does the trick 1 AND 2 mentioned above. Although both are syntactically correct, that is, the order of dots and quotes is correct, none of the lines opens the slide AND AND populates the div.

1ST LINE PROPOSED:

This line lets the slide panel open but it does not transmit the id_cruise value

```
$sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#\"' .' id=\"' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

2ND LINE PROPOSED

This line DOES NOT open and does NOT populate either the DIV box inside that panel, (you can see some shaking of where the panel was, even though it doesnt open). If you look at the line, it seems to me, there is an extra id that would not need to be there, it is twice it says both id = id_cruise....

```
$sOutput .= '"<a href=\"?id=' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" id=\"' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

AND THE JQUERY SNIPPET THAT SHOULD BE ACTIVATED BY THE CLICK OF THE LINK AND BY THE PASSING OF THE PARAMETER IS THIS

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.flip').live('click',function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
 $('#reviews').load('SendIdToDatabase.php', {id_cruise: this.id});
  });
});

</script>
```

AN ALTERNATIVE SNIPPET WAS PROPOSED YESTERDAY, BUT THE PROBLEM IS THE SAME

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.flip').live('click',function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
     DoSomethingWith(this.id);
     });
});

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function DoSomethingWith(id) {
  $.get("SendIdToDatabase.php", {id_cruise:"id"}, AnotherFunction);
}
function AnotherFunction(str) {
 $("#reviews").html(str);                                                
}
</script>
```

So, this is it. To visualize how it works. Just imagine a table. Well, you click on a link and that table goes down as the slide panel opens up. Inside that panel there is a div, that, as you see, loads the content of the php file called SendIdToDatabase.php

**UPDATE**

Well the issue, as you will see in the answer was not only on the link but also in one line of the JQUERY snippet, the one that forwards the value to the sql php script. It had a double quote on it and would send the value as a literal letter. Some say that the quotes would not make any difference. I definitively tell you it did all the difference in the world. Besides that, out of the two links proposed, only the first one works, the other one does not open the slide panel.

**UPDATE OF THE UPDATE**

Guffa or Göran insightfully pointed out that the second line does open the panel, but what happened (managed to know that even without seeing it visually!) that the page was reloaded again before the panel finished displaying. I believe, as I replied in the comment, that that was due to a double repetion of one part of the line, this one

```
'\" id=\"' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise'])
```

so, either remove that part, of use the first line. I used the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason the value was not being passed on, was that there were double quotes on the id where there should have been none, here `id_cruise:"id"` I created a print id_cruise in the php script to see if it ever received a value indeed, and guess what it received ? `id`.

That is it. Take the quotes out and you have a variable and not a literal. Just that, So, I dont know if the simplified snippet works, dont want to try. I just choose the one from Jeff which looks well designed in the sense that you can see a logical succession of events so there should not be a reason why this would not work. Thanks to Jason this morning for the perfect syntax of the long line and thanks a million for all those who helped tried to help. good night

Answer (score 0):

One problem is definitely that you don't stop the default action of the link. I'm not sure what the problem is with the first line (it might be that the load request is stopped because the link is followed), but the second will reload the page. Use the `preventDefault` method to stop the browser from following the link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.flip').live('click',function(e){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $('#reviews').load('SendIdToDatabase.php', {id_cruise: this.id});
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

With that it should work with either of your lines. It's only the URL that differs, and that is not used.

Comment: Issue is solved, I have posted my answer but actually it was the work of many people who helped, so it is their answer actually, i just spotted a tiny thing that was what prevented the stuff from working

Comment: @Alvaro: I don't see anything in the posted code that addresses the problem. The alternative code does have the error with the quotation marks, but removing the quotation marks doesn't make the alternative code work, it only makes it do the same as the original code.

Comment: No, believe me, it works, it fully works. I am having it running on my laptop I have left the alternative code as it was so that people can see the error, but in the answer I explained why that worked. I used then the 1st of the lines + the alternative code where the JQUERY is splitted into two chunks. It works great

Comment: @Alvaro: What do you mean? There is nothing in the answer that explains why the alternative code would work any better.

Comment: Hello Göra, I believe the simplified versus the broken down code would both work the same, so long you really take the quotes out of the assignment id_cruise:"id" . Another thing I have mentioned in the updated posting is that only the first line works, the second one does not open the panel.

Comment: @Alvaro: You are missing the point. The quotation marks does make a difference, but there was no quotation marks in the original code. They were introduced in the alternative code, and removing them makes the alternative code work as the original code. The panel will actually load for both lines, but the second line will cause the page to reload so the panel doesn't have time to show up. You should prevent the default action of the link as I described in the answer, so that it doesn't interfer with loading the content.

Comment: Alright, glad to understand why the second line was doing that thank you for your insightful solution.

Comment: and if I may add, I think the reason why the second line would cause the page to reload is because there was a double definition of id = row['id_cruise'] to which I made a mention when I presented the two lines. So, wouldnt actually also removing the second id = id_cruise cause the same effect as the prevent ?

Comment: Just for curiosity, I tried the simplified code of "Load". Does not populate the div box. No content is loaded. So, I stay with the two snippets version of Jeff.

Comment: @No, the extra id in the code is irrelevant. It's a parameter in the URL, and the URL should not be used. The significant difference between the lines is that the first has `#` as URL, so that goes to a bookmark on the same page instead of reloading the page. One possible reason that you can't get the `load` method to work would be that it does a post if you use an object as data, and if you expect a GET request you won't see the data. Using `'id_cruise='+this.id` instead of `{id_cruise: this.id}` would fix that.